# How to use default lightning email template in salesforce

Tags: email, salesforce-lightning

I am calling Salesforce classic email template through URL :
/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor

I have tried to create a lightning component for email where I created the email functionality But that doesn't fit my requirement.

I need to use the default lightning email template and call it from  URL or VF page or any other method. URL hack is not working here so is there any way to do so.